# java android IOException processing: 26

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, mapactivity

i m trying to connect to google map api using an MapActivity
i've generate the key using keytool and i 've added it to google console

> 10-08 00:43:07.759: W/System.err(549): IOException processing: 26
>   10-08 00:43:07.769: W/System.err(549): java.io.IOException: Server
>   returned: 3 10-08 00:43:07.769: W/System.err(549):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
>   10-08 00:43:07.769: W/System.err(549):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
>   10-08 00:43:07.789: W/System.err(549):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
>   10-08 00:43:07.789: W/System.err(549):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
>   10-08 00:43:07.789: W/System.err(549):    at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
>   10-08 00:43:07.814: W/System.err(549):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the API key not matching correctly.  It should be simple, but it seems this happens consistently while starting out.

run through this page from google and get their project working.  You will then know that you API key is working correctly

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Once you have that running, just apply the process to your current project (generate a new API key though)

** Quick update... if you are signing in in debug mode, be sure to generate your SHA-1 code using your terminal and the following values

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

for more detail on signing in with a debug / release key: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Answer (score 0):

Put the following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
    android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

put your key in such a way

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="the key" />
```

hope it will help you and for more you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631255/google-map-v2-with-android-is-not-working) discussion ..